# Stuck on heroku setup page for ruby

Tags: ruby, heroku

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#web-rb

I'm stuck at the "write your app" part. It gives a *hello world* example, so I tried doing that with vim:

The `web.rb` file reads as follows.

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do

      "hello, world"
end
```

But, when I try and do: `heroku addons:add newrelic:stark --app web.rb`,
it says failed. app not found.

I'm probably missing something "obvious" because I've actually never worked with Heroku and hardly any Ruby before. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're at "Write Your App", you haven't created a Heroku application yet, you've only just started writing the code for it.

Adding the newrelic add-on to a non-existent heroku app would likely give you that error.

Don't get ahead of yourself, finish the tutorial on creating the Heroku application before trying to add things to it.

Comment: I tried using their suggested hello world example Ruby program but I don't think I did it right since it's not recognizing it. Do I need to make a new directory called apps and put it in there? I don't understand what to do next when they say on the site, "here’s a “hello, world” sourcefile you can use. Sorry, but I'm very much a noob here.

Comment: You didn't skip any steps?  All you posted was the web.rb, which is the first of many steps to creating the hello world application.  There's the Gemfile, Procfile, git repository, `heroku create`, and `git push heroku`.  All on the page you posted, one right after another.  Follow the steps and you should have a hello world app on Heroku.

Comment: Working from the top of the page down, I'm able to login and create keys but according to the setup page, the creation of the Gemfile comes after the hello world example. It doesn't say much about how to create the Gemfile. Also from the page, commands like bundle exec and bundle install don't seem to be recognized.

Comment: Do you have Ruby and Bundler installed?  Listed in [the prerequisites](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#prerequisites).  If `bundle exec` and `bundle install` aren't working, you likely don't have Bundler.  I'd start by following a basic Sinatra tutorial and get that working before trying to mess with Heroku deployment.